# How to stop the spring MVC controller execution if client close the browser tab?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, websocket, spring-websocket

I'm developing a web app that use a spring websocket connection to send multiple message to a specific user.
I've got a spring mvc controller which when receive a STOMP from the client start sending message to the user. It's something like this:

```
@Controller
public class Controller{
     @Autowired
     private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

     @MessageMapping("/")
     @SendToUser("/queue/user")
     public void myMethod(ClientMessage msg, Principal principal){
          Object myObject = new Object();
          //stuff
          while(true){
               //more stuff
               this.template.convertAndSendToUser(principal.getName(), "/queue/user", myObject);
          }
     }
}
```

Now my question is: there's a way to know when the client close (or reload) the browser tab?
I want to exit from the while cycle when the client close the tab to terminate the controller execution.
I was thinking to stop the while cycle by checking something, like: `while(!session.isClose())`
Can anyone help me out with this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I post my solution if anyone could need it.

I don't really know if i'm doing things correctly but i moved the SessionDisconnectEvent listener from a specific class to my controller. So, now the controller implements the ApplicationListener and override the onApplicationEvent. When the user close the tab a boolean is setted to true and the controller stops its execution.
Now i've got something like this:

```
@Controller
public class Controller implements ApplicationListener<SessionDisconnectEvent>{

     @Autowired
     private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

     private boolean disconnected;

     @MessageMapping("/")
     @SendToUser("/queue/user")
     public void myMethod(ClientMessage msg, Principal principal){
          Object myObject = new Object();
          //stuff
          while(!disconnected){
               //more stuff
               this.template.convertAndSendToUser(principal.getName(), "/queue/user", myObject);
          }
     }

     @EventListener
     @Override
     public void onApplicationEvent(SessionDisconnectEvent  applicationEvent) {
          System.out.println("SESSION " + applicationEvent.getSessionId() + " DISCONNECTED");
          this.graphService.setDisconnect(true);
     }
}
```